# How does Windows 7 determine, if you need admin rights? (vc60)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++-6, administrator

**Problem:** I'm writing unittests for a Setup program in c++. The Setup needs admin rights, but the unittests do not. On starting the tests, I get asked for starting the test/program as Administrator.

This started happening when I included the rc-file of the original project.

**Edit:** I was upgrading this project to VS2010, but still using vc60, so there is no manifest support. This might be related.

Comment: Little reason to not tell us what the .rc file contains.  But yeah, having it contain a manifest that uses `requireAdminstrator` is the normal way to ask for UAC elevation.

Comment: regarding the answer, this is the bad part:
            VALUE "FileDescription", "Setup Module"
            VALUE "InternalName", "SETUP"
            VALUE "OriginalFilename", "SETUP.EXE"
            VALUE "ProductName", "Setup Module"

no such thing as manifest defined here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the resources contain a manifest, and a portion of the manifest states whether the program needs administrator access.  Since this is a setup utility, it probably has a manifest requiring administrator access and your tests picked it up when it tried to share the resource file.

(Other people are talking about the heuristics used to guess whether a program needs administrator access when it doesn't have a manifest.  For example, if you have an old program that was made before manifest files were common, the OS might try to guess whether it's an installer by looking for certain phrases like "setup" in the file name.  I believe there are other heuristics as well.  This is a hack for older programs that were written before manifests made it possible to explicitly declare your need for administrator access.)

You can fix your problem by providing your own manifest.  The easiest way is to use the [`/MANIFESTUAC`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384691.aspx) linker option.

If you're using an older toolchain, you'll probably have to make the manifest file yourself and include it in your resources.

The manifest is a chunk of XML.  The important bit for you would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0"  name="yourprogram.exe" type="win32"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker"/>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

To embed this in your resources, your .RC file should have:

```
1 RT_MANIFEST <filename>
```

If your SDK is so old that `RT_MANIFEST` is not defined, you can define it yourself:

```
#define RT_MANIFEST 24
```

Answer (score 1):

One criteria for evaluating the needed rights for an application is the name.
So if the name *contains* the Word "Setup", you will be asked for admin rights.

Also, as this started with the rc file, another criteria are the names written in the rc-File, under "Version". In my case in "VS_VERSION_INFO".
The following entries are should not *contain* the word Setup:

```
FileDescription
InternalName
OriginalFilename
ProductName
```

You might change any occurance of "Setup" to "Settup". That would prevent the dialog. 
Even though, you might not be able to change this in the "real" rc-file.

Comment: Or you can add a manifest file that explicitly tells Windows whether you do or do not require admin rights.

Comment: Thank you for this information, if this is correct. Can you point at official docs if such exists? Assuming that the info is correct, this is almost not inane and user-hostile enough to be Microsoft, surely there must be more?

Comment: I didn't find any official ressources, but found out by trying. Though, it might be only an issue, if you don't have manifest support, as I do in this case.There's just a comment here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384608.aspx